# Simple tagged versus simple inheritance design: which scales better?

Tags: java, scalability

I have a very simple value-based class that is intended to be used in an application server environment.  I'd like to choose a design that enables the best scalability (these simple classes are illustrative):

**Tagged:**

```
public class Value {
    private final long    m_value;
    private final boolean m_kind;

    private Value(long value, boolean tag) { 
        this.m_value = value; 
        this.m_kind  = tag;
    }

    public long getValue()  { return m_value; }
    public boolean kindOf() { return m_kind; }

    public static Value of(long value, boolean tag) {
        return new Value(value, tag);
    }
}
```

The tagged Value class is a simple class with no accessible constructor and a static factory method that includes a field for a tag `m_kind`, i.e. a field that describes a special attribute of the value (precisely what isn't important for this example).  Because this is a tagged class, it may also be represented using an inheritance hierarchy:

**Hierarchy:**

```
public abstract class Value {
    private final long    m_value;

    private Value(long value) { 
        this.m_value = value; 
    }

    public long getValue()  { return m_value; }
    public abstract boolean kindOf();

    public static Value of(long value, boolean kind) {
        return (kind) 
            ? new TrueValue(value);
            : new FalseValue(value);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TrueValue extends Value {

    TrueValue(long value) { super(value); }

    @Override
    public boolean kindOf() { return true; }
}
```

and

```
public class FalseValue extends Value {

    FalseValue(long value) { super(value); }

    @Override
    public boolean kindOf() { return false; }
}
```

From the client perspective, these two solutions behave exactly the same.

The Tagged solution requires an additional instance field in order to describe an object's complete state, whereas the state in the Hierarchical solution is partly described by the hierarchy itself and so requires one less field (but it does require a hierarchy).

In a resource constrained Java server environment, which of these solutions provides better scalability or are the differences too small to be important?

Comment: Seems primarily opinion based; I'd say avoid inheritance unless you plan to implement different functionality for each. Like methods that only work with ```TrueValues```. Otherwise, it's easier to add new types with the first design. But if you only ever have 2 types, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: *"Otherwise, it's easier to add new types with the first design."* ... this can't possibly be true.  An important reason to have inheritance at all is for code reuse and to help types evolve.  "Favor hierarchies over tagged classes" -- Effective Java, 2nd Ed.  While it may be true that the resource utilization for the two strategies is too small to be important, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Whether the inheritance-based approach actually uses less space depends on whether Java (or perhaps the particular Java compiler you use) is allowed to omit the vtable (method table) pointer from instances of the tag-based class.  If (as in C++) the vtable pointers can be omitted, then despite the extra `bool` it will likely be *smaller*.  And it will definitely be faster as all method calls can be direct (vs. via pointer).  Regardless, if the objects are mutable and you need to be able to change an object from one "kind" to another, you'll be forced to use tags.

Comment: @scottb I was actually talking about types of tags, right now you only have true and false, but if you want a third or fourth kind. Adding it would be as simple as calling the constructor with a different value (assuming the value is not actually a ```boolean``` in the real implementation).  "Favor hierarchies over tagged classes", yes "Favor". There are still cases in which tagged classes are _better_ (not saying this is one).  I was just offering my insight on the situation. I actually read past the part of the question asking about the resources, sorry.

Comment: @JornVernee: the example classes are illustrative.  In this case, the tag is boolean solely for simplicity.   In the use case, the tag is an enum constant (which, in this case, works fine since the tag-dependent implementation differences can be wrapped into the rich enum type).  My intent here was not to discuss "tagged versus hierarchy" but instead to learn about the resource costs of each approach.